How can I remove large horizontal space in an aligned-environment?
Simple question, actually: How can I remove the large horizontal space between "f" and "\in" here:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \left\{f\in C:\begin{aligned}&f&&\in A\text{ and }\\&f&&\in B\end{aligned}\right\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}

I've actually used the split-environment before, but my latex compiler told me that this is not allowed and it automatically replaced it with aligned. Now I got the spacing problem ...
Here is the rendered output:

EDIT: I'm using && to get left-alignment of "\in" btw.

What if you move the f's into the slots with \in?

@mickep That's something which got lost in my simplification. In my actual equation, these are different fs occupying different amount of space and the \ins should be aligned as well.

You need just one &.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \left\{f\in C:\begin{aligned}f &\in A\text{ and }\\f &\in B\end{aligned}\right\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}


If you really need multiple alignment points, use alignedat that doesn't add space between columns.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left\{
  f\in C:
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
  &f &&\in A\text{ and } \\ &a+b &&\in B
  \end{alignedat}
\right\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}



The second suggestion is working for me! In my actual equation, there are actually two different fs which occupy different amount of space, which is why I really need two alignment points.

@0xbadf00d I suspected it, that's why I added the second possibility. Next time, it's better not to simplify too much.
